# Why does NSLog() not do anything if it's after a method's return?

Tags: objective-c, return

I noticed that when my method runs, nothing is printed to the console:

```
- (BOOL)theTemporyFunction
{
    return YES;
    NSLog(@"Events");
}
```

but when I change the order of the statements:

```
- (BOOL)theTemporyFunction
{
    NSLog(@"Events");
    return YES;
}
```

the `NSLog()` does run.

Both versions compile, so why doesn't `NSLog()` seem to work in the first?

Comment: No language executes code after returning!.

Comment: Don't you get a warning from xcode?

Comment: `return` does just that, it returns a value. Nothing after a `return` will ever be run. As this is a very elementary idea in programming, I think you would receive less down-votes in the future if you read an introductory book on programming before posting questions. I recommend [Learn to Program](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/), by Chris Pine. It also serves as a very good primer on the Ruby programming language.

Comment: @Vignesh - ahm... Java finally block... ahm... ;) but in general, you're right.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet. That's an exotic block. I agree. Thanks!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return` is the last statement that is executed in a function. After the [return statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement) the function **returns** the control to the caller.

For example:

```
function1                                      function2
int x;
function2();-----------------------------+
                                         +---->puts("function2 - should be called");
                                         +-----return;
puts("back to function1");<--------------+     puts("should not be called");
```

Comment: the compiler even removes any code after a return statement, as it cannot be reached at any time.

Comment: Yes, code after the return statement is not executed (e.g. dead code)

Answer (score 3):

you really need to learn programming basics.. `return` - as it states - you are returning from the method execution to the previous context >> you are leaving the method at this point.