# releasing object after return, is it good practice?

Tags: objective-c, ios

i am just wondering if we can do so:

```
 SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    id repr = [parser objectWithString:self];

    return repr;
    [parser release];
```

So releasing object after returning it, is this a good practice? thanx for any information :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: NO

You can not execute *anything* after a `return` statement.

Instead you should `autorelease` the object. That will deallocate it within the next cleanup run of the surrounding AutoreleasePool.

```c
SBJsonParser *parser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] autorelease];
return [parser objectWithString:self];
```

Comment: Would there be anything wrong with getting `repr` and then `release`ing `parser`, before returning?

Comment: Nope, that would be possible as well. I personally just prefer that compact style.

Answer (score 1):

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init]]autorealease];//<<< auto release the object on creaion
    id repr = [parser objectWithString:self];

    return repr;
```

Comment: Oh, Thanx a lot for your reply, actually yes i know that way, but i am wondering about the way of releasing the Object after turning it :)

Answer (score 0):

You compiler will not reach the any line after the return statement(Except When you use finally statement.). You got to `autorelease` it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code after return statement won't even be executed. glogic's solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Have you learned programming basics? After a return statement, nothing is executed.

See:
[Why does NSLog() not do anything if it's after a method's return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482655/why-does-nslog-not-do-anything-if-its-after-a-methods-return)

Answer (score 0):

> > A method returns to the code that invoked it when it
>
> - completes all the statements in the method
> - reaches a return statement
> - or throws an exception.